# This is not JSON but similar, what language is this?

Tags: json, format

I am parsing a larger JSON and one field (10) contains some strange data.

```
"10": "a:2:{s:8:\"latitude\";s:17:\"55.50636887209855\";s:9:\"longitude\";s:18:\"-4.576417238098154\";}"
```

The data is clearly latitude and longitude with the corresponding values. But I would like to parse this data correctly and I have never seen this format.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like a raw self-defined format, not like a language.
So you have to write your own code to process it.
Using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) you can parse the input like this:

```bash
INPUT='
{
  "10": "a:2:{s:8:\"latitude\";s:17:\"55.50636887209855\";s:9:\"longitude\";s:18:\"-4.576417238098154\";}"
}
'

jq '.["10"] |= (. / ";" | map(match("\"(.*)\"").captures[0].string | tonumber? // .))' <<< "$INPUT"
```

**Output**

```json
{
  "10": [
    "latitude",
    55.50636887209855,
    "longitude",
    -4.576417238098154
  ]
}
```

---

**Second version**

```bash
INPUT='
{
  "10": "a:2:{s:8:\"latitude\";s:17:\"55.50636887209855\";s:9:\"longitude\";s:18:\"-4.576417238098154\";}"
}
'

jq '.["10"] |= (. / ";" | map(match("\"(.*)\"").captures[0].string | tonumber? // .)
                | {(.[0]): .[1], (.[2]): .[3]} )' <<< "$INPUT"
```

**Output**

```json
{
  "10": {
    "latitude": 55.50636887209855,
    "longitude": -4.576417238098154
  }
}
```

---

**Remark**

The code only works if this format contains 4 fields separated by `;` with values enclosed by `\"`